# Tagging exceptions in Ruby, an explanation/alternative

Tags: ruby, exception

I've read one tip for tagging your own exceptions in case you have your own library:

```
module AcmeHttp
  module Error; end
end

begin
  begin
    raise IOError, "Some IO error"
  rescue Exception => error
    error.extend(AcmeHttp::Error)
    raise
  end
rescue AcmeHttp::Error => error
  puts "Rescued AcmeHttp::Error: #{error}"
end
```

I'm not really sure how `error.extend(AcmeHttp::Error)` works and how later you can actually rescue using it. Also, is there some more elegant approach to tagging exceptions from your own library?

Comment: `extend` is normal Ruby. The reason is so that underlying causes are captured. Another approach is http://www.jayway.com/2011/05/25/ruby-an-exceptional-language/.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object#extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-extend) adds the instance methods of one or more modules, to the receiver object.

So when you do `error.extend(AcmeHttp::Error)` you are actually adding the instance methods of the `AcmeHttp::Error` module to `error` which is an exception (actually a class object).

Comment: And why does AcmeHttp::Error matches rescue?

Comment: Because `extend` makes `AcmeHttp::Error` a superclass of `error`'s singleton class. Like @DaveNewton in his comment on your question, `extend` has nothing to do with exception, it's just basic Ruby.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag is there a way to see this ancestor chain, in the same way like you would do AnyClass.ancestors (just this time, it's for objects)?